# How do I import multiple csv files in gnumeric?

Tags: gnome, spreadsheet, gnumeric

I am trying to import multiple csv files into gnumeric so that each one is a separate sheet in the workbook. This is relatively simple in Excel but I cannot work out how to do it in gnumeric.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it appears manually pasting CSV data into Gnumeric is currently (early 2017) the best answer.  Cat the csv file in a shell, cut the lines to the clipboard, and use the Gnumeric Edit -> paste option.  Its not too bad, Gnumeric will use an importer, recognize the paste data is in CSV format, and let you adjust the parsing and column formats before actually doing the paste.